# How to increase maximum of json response upto int64

Tags: asp.net, json

I want to set Json response upto `int64`.
Here is my code.

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
 serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int64.MaxValue;
```

I am getting an error:

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

Comment: whats the error you are getting than?

Comment: **Additional information: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually created jsonData using stringbuilder without serialization.